# Finding the $\lim\limits_{x \to 0+} (\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{\arctan x})$

Tags: calculus

Right so, so far I have gotten the denominators the same and have the achieved the indeterminate 0/0 as $\lim\limits_{x \to 0+} \frac{\arctan x - x}{x\arctan x}$ once I apply L' Hospital's Rule though, it gets really messy. So I am wondering if there is a more elegant or efficient way to find the answer without having to deal with the nesting fractions.

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule should be good enough. Just need few more patience to get it.

Comment: Maybe you could substitute $arctanx = y$, so you'll have $\frac{1}{tgy}-\frac{1}{y}= \frac{cosy}{siny}-\frac{1}{y}$. Than you can replace $siny \sim y$(as $y\to 0$). Other part is obvious. I mean $\frac{cosy-1}{y}= -\frac{sin^{2} \frac{y}{2}}{\frac{y}{2}}$. So seemeingly it should approach 0.

Comment: Yes, l'Hôpital should be enough together with $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan (x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}=1$.

Comment: Two who comment above are as bad as the original posted in proper use of MathJax. I cleaned it up in the posted question.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\arctan x - x}{x\arctan x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\left(\dfrac 1 {1+x^2} \right) - 1}{x\left( \dfrac 1 {1+x^2} \right) + 1\cdot\arctan x} \\[10pt]
= {} & \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1 - (1+x^2)}{ x + (1+x^2) \arctan x } = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{-x^2}{x + (1+x^2)\arctan x} \\[10pt]
= {} & \left( \lim_{x\to0} \frac {\left(\dfrac x {\arctan x}\right)} {\left( \dfrac x {\arctan x} \right) + (1+x^2)} \right) \cdot \left( \lim_{x\to0} (-x) \right) \\[10pt]
\end{align}

Now use the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \frac x {\arctan x} = 1.$

This is to be expected because $x \arctan x$ crosses the axis with a slope of $1$ and is an odd function, so no $x^2$ term can appear in its power series, so in $\arctan x - x$ the $x$ term cancels and there's no $x^2$ term, so it's like $x^3 + \text{higher-degree terms}$, whereas $x\arctan x$ is like $x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

With $y=\arctan(x)$, we get

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\arctan(x)-x}{x\arctan(x)}=\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{y-\tan(y)}{\tan(y)y}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{y-\tan(y)}{y^2}\frac{y}{\tan(y)}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{1-(1+y^2)}{2y}*1$$

$$=\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{-y^2}{2y}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

May be, you could have used Taylor series $$\tan^{-1}(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ So $$\frac 1{\tan^{-1}(x)}=\frac 1{x-\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)}=\frac 1 x\times \frac 1{1-\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right)}=\frac 1 x\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right) \right)$$ which finally make $$\frac 1 x-\frac 1{\tan^{-1}(x)}=\frac 1 x-\frac 1 x\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3}+O\left(x^3\right) \right)=-\frac{x}{3}+O\left(x^2\right)$$